# How to deactivate the button that control auto open and close of side mirrors

Tags: wing-mirrors

I crashed the passenger side mirror socket and it's not working properly. Can I deactivate the button that control auto open and close of the mirror so that it stays the same position? At the moment, each time when I start the car, the mirror will swing outward and is not able to stay at a certain position. It's trying to open a bit more but it can't, so the mirror keeps clicking. I have to pull it in a bit until it can stop.

Comment: Could you tell us the make, model and year of the car?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what the car is, pull the door trim and disconnect the mirror in question. There may or may not be a disable button, check your owners manual.

If the mirrors automatically open and close than assume it's computer controlled and disabling the fold mirror button will not do anything.

Comment: ..or the fuse...